# xpdf batch file: how to change file name?

Tags: batch-file, pdf, xpdf

I'm using a simple batch file calling the xpdf engine to convert a PDF to a TXT file. Right now, the resulting txt file's name is the same as the PDF's, except the extension has been changed to .txt of course. However, I want to add some text behind the original file name, how can I do this? For example, if there's a PDF called test.pdf, it should be converted to text and stored in a txt file called testFULL.txt.

This is the current batch file I have:
`for /R %%s in (*.pdf) do "C:\xpdf\bin32\pdftotext" -raw "%%s"`

Comment: I would think you would have to look at the help for your conversion program to see if you can specify an output file name.

Comment: See if your conversion program can accept a parameter like this **`"%%~dpnsFULL%%~xs"`** as your output filename with **`"%%s"`** as the input filename.

Comment: @Compo, `Usage: pdftotext [options] <PDF-file> [<text-file>]` (from executing `pdftotext.exe` without arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment showing that the output text file is a parameter:

```bat
for /R %%s in (*.pdf) do "C:\xpdf\bin32\pdftotext" -raw "%%s" "%%~dpnsFULL.txt"
```